# Time format laravel vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing an application with laravel and vue js.
In this application I have to enable the recording of period of hours. A check is done so as not to allow the recording if the period already exists.

My problem is at the validation level. I created a custom rule.

When I send my form with axios, the time is in hh: mm format.
Except my validation works only with a format hh: mm: ss.
How can I get axios to send the correct format?

Exemple to input form :

```
<input type="time" required class="form-control input_modal" name="start" v-model="form.start" />
```

Exemple validation rule:

```
$date = request('date');
$start = request('start');
$end = request('end');


$divers = Divers::where('date_id', $date)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->where(
                [
                    ['start', '<=', $start],
                    ['end', '>', $start],
                ]

            )
            ->orWhere([
                ['start', '<', $end],
                ['end', '>', $end]
            ])
            ->orWhere([
                ['start', '>', $start],
                ['end', '<', $end]
            ])
            ->get();
```

Thanks !

Comment: "How can I get axios to send the correct format?" the only code you didn't show is your axios code :) ... at the post just process the time variable in the format that you want to send it, or at the Controller convert it to the one you will receive

Comment: Thank you @Svetoslav !
I used variables formatted with the correct format for my validation rule. I format variables in my controller.

Comment: Do you care about the accuracy of seconds? you can always append ": 00" to the model 'form.start' before submitting your request